# How to change post status in hook?

Tags: plugin-development, publish, post-status

I have similar problem as described in [How to trap "Publish" button to check for meta box validation?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7055/how-to-trap-publish-button-to-check-for-meta-box-validation)
Answer there is to hook into `save_post` and change post type. How can I do it?
I try to use `wp_transition_post_status` but it doesn't work for me...

```
function myHook( $post_ID, $post )
{

    wp_transition_post_status('pending', $post->post_status, $post );

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'myHook', 10, 2 );
```

Edit: I have clear wordpress installation without any plugins, additional code and similar

Comment: Please add your relevant code. "Try" is very vague...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the full post object as a second parameter on `save_post`. Use it to change the status just like the following code.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_78351_status', 10, 2 );

function wpse_78351_status( $post_ID, $post )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    if ( 'trash' !== $post->post_status ) //adjust the condition
    {
        $post->post_status = 'draft'; // use any post status
        wp_update_post( $post );
    }
}
```

See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69802/73) for a list of post statuses.

Comment: I also found another fix: add remove_action( 'save_post', 'myHook'); before wp_update_post( $post ); and add_action( 'save_post', 'myHook', 10, 2 ); after

It works :) Thank you a lot for help :)